# How can I see previously starred messages in chat?

Tags: support, chat

I like to star lots of things in chat as being interesting (which I believe was the point of it), but I would like to know **how can I see what I previously starred later on?** For example, when there are links to useful sources or items, I may want to see it on my work computer or on my home computer, in two separate locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already a feature. Above the stared list in chat - click: `show all 1234` - then filter the messages to just the ones you've starred by clicking `by me` under **Starred Messages**.